# Question for class

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, ifconfig

I have a question for class that I cannot figure out, I was hoping the helpful folks at Ask Ubuntu could help. The question is basically this: Your Linux system appears to have a DHCP problem. You decide to release and renew the DHCP lease by running the following command "SUDO IFCONFIG ETH0 DOWN". The command gives an error message saying Linux doesn't recognize the command. What's the problem? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: People answering this, please consider the following meta thread about homework assignments: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2224/allow-homework-questions Try to educate rather than simply answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very basic, has nothing to do with networking or DHCP. You should read the section 2(BASICS) in [Link](http://faculty.ucr.edu/~tgirke/Documents/UNIX/linux_manual.html). That will lead you to the answer. But to be frank its a pretty straight forward thing.

**N.B:** Didn't post answer as is, as I'm trying to `educate rather than simply answer.`
**Update:**
The answer is `LINUX command line is case sensitive`.

Comment: I'll post the exact answer after some time, if the still doesn't get the answer.

Comment: Oh gosh, I was looking into various DHCP problems and ended up reading into changing MAC addresses and all sorts of stuff. Didn't expect it to be so simple. Thanks again, I've got it.

Comment: @Tyler, You're welcome. Always start looking up from the basic stuff.. :)

Comment: @Tyler, Please mark as answer, I have updated with exact answer..